# How do I format a date like this with dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime-format

I have an instance of `DateTime` and I would like to format that to a String. How do I do that? I want to turn the date into a `string`, something like "May 14, 2020". I have not seen any solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages?q=intl) to formate `DateTime`.

To get "May 14, 2020" you can try the code below.

`DateFormat('MMMM dd, yyyy').format(dateTime)`